# Yet x So far in the meaning "up to now"

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

I often see sentences like:

> This is their best album yet.

Could I say "so far" instead? Or would that require present perfect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say *so far* instead of *yet* without changing the tense. Both sentences mean the same - "the best up to this point" - but can convey a different feeling.

The difference is that *yet* has a more positive association, i.e. that prior work has been good, but this work is better. Using *so far* sounds like prior work *could have been* poor/mediocre/average. That is not to say that *so far* means that prior work was not good, only that there is a feeling that the possibility exists.

Of course, it is also possible to write e.g. a review with a positive tone and still use *so far*.